# iOS app start or switch back to foreground very slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

The app built using xcode start or switch back to foreground very slow. After tapping the icon at home screen, it takes about 3 seconds to show the app. But the app downloaded from app store is very fast, after tapping the icon, it shows immediately.

Firstly I think it's my code's problem, but even I create a empty project and build it to my phone, it also start very slow, switching back to foreground is the same.

Then I think it was because xcode need setup communication with device, then I disconnect my phone with my computer, and through tapping the icon to open the app, problem the same, even I build release version.

Why is the app slower than downloaded app? Is it because the phone needs to go through the provision file to auth the app launching?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am experiencing the same thing and I could not find why.

Comment: @RoyLi It seems debug problem, production environment will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it takes longer for an application to open when starting from Xcode is because it takes a few seconds to attach to the debugger so you can see anything you print in the console and see any exceptions that happen.